# PoI Range query

Tags: mysql, point-of-interest, spatial-query

I have a dataset of 100,000 PoIs represented by (id, name, longitude, latitude)..

I would like to perform a large number (around 10,000) search operations on this dataset. each search operation should return the list of PoIs that exist within  a certain distance *range* from a given point defined by its longitude, latitude.

The points locations are defined as  values, where the search range distance is in Kilometers radius from a given longitude, latitude point.

I tried performing an exhaustive search to find the results of search, but it takes a lot of time to finish.

My dataset is stored in CSV file. I think it might be more efficient if certain structures like KD-tree or a database with Spatial Index is used for the search operation.

So, what methods do you think might be most efficient for performing this function ?

Comment: I think you have answered your own question!  Using spatial queries on a spatially enabled database with a spatial index (usually a variant of R trees) would be my first port of call rather than scanning a CSV. how are you currently performing your search?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response..

I am currently performing linear search on all items which is very slow given the number of search operations and the size of the search space.

Any recommendations or tutorials for using spatial indexed databases ? do you think MySQL should fit ?

Comment: The exact solution depends on the spatial reference system that you are using. In particular, it makes a difference if the coordinates are not in the same units that the range is in (e.g. longitude / latitude in degrees, range in metres). Can you update your question with these details (click edit below the question) to make sure that the answer meets your needs?

Comment: @BradHards done .. Please have a look.